# How to get different number of ticks and labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can't work out how to reduce a number of tick labels in my plot while preserving the number of ticks. Is there a way to do it or can I only have as many ticks as the number of labels? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set for some ticks empty tick labels.

```
# based on http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 4, 9, 6]
labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs', '', 'Slogs']

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
# You can specify a rotation for the tick labels in degrees or with keywords.
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
# Pad margins so that markers don't get clipped by the axes
plt.margins(0.2)
# Tweak spacing to prevent clipping of tick-labels
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Nearly there! So just how should I define these labels with large number of data (when my labels are numerical)? For example if x=np.arange(0,100,1) and I want my labels to be at 10, 20, ... etc.? I tried lables = np.arange(0,100,10), but it didn't work... Thanks

Comment: Ok, I figured how to get around it. Simply by an if loop of divisibility!

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer my comment on Serenity's answer, here's how to get the numerical labels.

```
x = range(100)
labels = []
for i in x:
    if i % 10 == 0:
        i=i
    else:
        i=' '
    labels.append(i)
```

And this does the job.